# Make a symbolic link in windows 10 that is available to without admin rights

Tags: windows-10

On windows 10 I can crate a symlink by opening the command line with admin rights and using

```
mklink CopasiSE "C:\path\to\CopasiSE.exe"
```

Now typing `CopasiSE` into the command line works as expected by executing the CopasiSE executable but only when using a command window with admin rights. When not using a command window with admin rights I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Ciaran>CopasiSE
'CopasiSE' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My question is how do I enable the command `CopasiSE` to be available without admin rights?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to add, "C:\path\to\CopasiSE.exe", to the user's PATH variable?  Of course your [syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx) is also slightly off.  Even if you fix it, the error your getting involves not being able to find the file.  Provide the output of the first command is suspect that's not actually working.  Update your question, please do not reply to this comment, I plan to delete it.

Comment: Specifically, the command your running should be more mklink "C:/Example.exe" "C:/Director/Program.exe".  Which would allow you run Example.exe from the root directory on C which would start Program.exe any other directory requires the path be in the variable...

Comment: Or make a .bat file with that path to the exe and put it where the user can access it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ramhound. I solved actualyl the problem by using your first suggestion and adding to the PATH variable but the question was informative for me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you've created the symlink inside an Admin-specific location.

The correct way to make a symlink is to define the entire path. If you wish to make it accessible to other users, the path will have to be in a location that the others users can access.

In this case, it should be something like this:

```
mklink "C:\PublicPath\CopasiSE.exe" "C:\path\to\CopasiSE.exe"
```